# Position:relative wrapping and element height?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a simple TextArea and a button

[image]

When the button is clicked , I need to `wrap` (exactly) the text area with a red div (`border:solid 1px red`)

*p.s this wrapper div must be `position:relative` because I need to add future absolute positioned elements*

And so I wrote this code :

```
$(".btn").on('click',function (){
 
 $(".myTextArea").wrap($('<span/>', {
                    "class": 'msgAbsWrap',
                    "style": "position:relative;display:inline" /*it's inline by default ,I know*/
                  
                }));
});
```

but the problem is that it doesn't wrap it as it should :

[image]

- why is it happenning ?
- How can I make the red div wrap (exactly) the textarea ?

<strike>[**JSBIN**](http://jsbin.com/izopaz/2/edit)</strike>

p.s. Im using chrome v 26.

## edit

(**my bad**) I forgot to remove the width from the textArea (after 1000 testings). it should be `width:100%` . can you please try now ?

[**JSBIN NEW**](http://jsbin.com/izopaz/10/edit)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the display style of the span to `display: inline-block;`

```
$(".myTextArea").wrap($('<span/>', {
    "class": 'msgAbsWrap',
    "style": "position:relative; display:inline-block; width: 100%;"
}));
```

Demo: [JSBIN](http://jsbin.com/izopaz/15/edit)

Comment: +1 it did work. however (**my bad**) I forgot to remove the width from the textArea. it should be `width:100%` . can you please try now ? http://jsbin.com/izopaz/10/edit

Comment: yup. working. thanks.why the wrapper messed the width ? (in my sample)?

Answer (score 1):

You can do these changes to take effects:

### CSS:

```
.msgAbsWrap {
   border:solid 1px red;
   display:inline-block;
   width:100%;
   position:relative;
}
```

### jQuery:

```
$(".btn").on('click', function () {
  $(".myTextArea").wrap($('<span/>', {
        "class": 'msgAbsWrap'
  }));
});
```

#### [Checkout the updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3r5eY/1/)

Comment: please read my update. the width is not 400px . it should be 100%.

Answer (score 0):

Change it to this:

```
$(".btn").on('click',function (){
    $(".myTextArea").attr('class', 'msgAbsWrap');
});
```

jsbin: http://jsbin.com/izopaz/12/

Comment: you didnt read my question at all. I need to add a wrapper div for future abs elements.

Answer (score 0):

Do it like this:

```
$(".btn").on('click',function (){

 $(".myTextArea").wrap($('<div></div>', {
    "class": 'msgAbsWrap',
    "style": "position:relative;"
 }));

});
```

Check this example: [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/izopaz/13/edit)

Comment: _How can I make the red div wrap (**exactly**) the textarea_.... your solution doesnt work.